# Ddns mx record configuration

Tags: domain-name-system, email, exchange-2013

I have installed exchange 2013 in my test lab. Everything works fine internally. Now I want to send and receive e-mail from internet. I have installed no-ip client tool in my exchange server. That no-ip domain name is pointing to my DSL router. Now I am having dynamic IP. I have an public domain name as well. Can anyone one suggests how I can send and receive mails from internet and how I can place MX record

Regards,
Karthick.

Answer (score 1):

If your router supports ddns (dynamic dns) you can register on one of free ddns websites, create subdomain yourdomain.ddnsservice and set your mx record to point to yourwebsite.ddnsservice with shortest ttl you can chose:

yourdomain. 300 in mx 0 yourdomain.ddnsservice.

Setting mx record with small ttl value will allow more frequent check which you prefere in this case, as you're using dynamic Ip

Comment: Hi thanks for your suggestion.  Can you tell me where i have to create MX record. in Router or no-ip DNS console or Local DNS server.

Comment: MX record should be set in your dns zone on yourdomain nameservers. Also, you would have to set ddns on your router, so just follow guidelines from ddns service that you decide to use